# UpperCaseAdapter does not support json Array

Tags: java, json, gson

I have created a UpperCaseAdapter  to upperCase all the keys of a json ,

But not working as expected

Here is my UpperCaseAdapter  code , i want to also upper case the arrays part but it is not the case for me , how could correct that ?

```
public static class UpperCaseAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Map<String, Object>>, JsonDeserializer<Map<String, Object>> {
    public static final Type TYPE = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType();

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Map<String, Object> src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        // TODO implement serialization if needed
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : json.getAsJsonObject().entrySet()) {
            Object value = null;
            if (entry.getValue().isJsonPrimitive()) {
                value = entry.getValue().getAsString();
            } else if (entry.getValue().isJsonObject()) {
                value = context.deserialize(entry.getValue(), TYPE); // deserialize the object using the same type
            } else if (entry.getValue().isJsonArray()) {
                // TODO implement deserailization of array
            } else if (entry.getValue().isJsonNull()) {
                // skip nulls
                continue;
            }
            map.put(entry.getKey().toUpperCase(), value); //toUpperCase() is what we want
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

and this code is to call my   `UpperCaseAdapter`

```
String payload = input_row.body;
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(json_routine.UpperCaseAdapter.TYPE, new 
json_routine.UpperCaseAdapter())
            .create();
Map<String, Object> mapDeserialized = gson.fromJson(payload, 
json_routine.UpperCaseAdapter.TYPE);

System.out.println("**** body_WS" + gson.toJson(mapDeserialized));
```

My body looks like this :

```
 {
"transactionId": 181,
"ExtWareHouseId ": "toto",
"OwnerCode": "toto",
"ClientCode": "toto",
"activityId": toto,
"taskTypeCode": "01",
"activated": "2023-02-06T17:33:48.1905172+01:00",
"StartDate ": "2023-01-24T15:19:12.8591383+01:00",
"userCode": "toto",
"equipmentId": "01",
"PortId": "1",
"printerName": "",
"shipments": [
{
  "shipmentId": 2,
  "picklistId": "Example",
  "ExtOrderId": "23-127",
  "boxType": "120"
  }
 ]
}
```

I get the following result :

```
{
 "EXTWAREHOUSEID ":"toto",
 "PRINTERNAME":"",
 "TRANSACTIONID":"181",
 "OWNERCODE":"toto",
 "ACTIVITYID":"1072",
 "EQUIPMENTID":"01",
 "USERCODE":"toto",
 "STARTDATE ":"2023-01-24T15:19:12.8591383+01:00",
 "ACTIVATED":"2023-02-06T17:33:48.1905172+01:00",
 "TASKTYPECODE":"01",
 "CLIENTCODE":"toto",
 "PORTID":"1"
}
```

The `shipments` part is missing , how could i correct my adapter to get a correct result

Any help on this , i'm stack on how to Upper case Array keys

Comment: Maybe one solution would be to parse it as `Map<String, Object>` (or `JsonObject`) and then recursively go through the nested `Map` (respectively `JsonObject`) values and uppercase all keys. That would not require any custom adapter.

Comment: thank you about the suggestion , i will give a try